# При попытке поднять высоту Terrain в Unity это делает не корректно

Tags: unity3d, terrain

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда выбираю инструмент для поднятия ландшафта оно это делает очень странным образом, не ровным кругом, а странными угловатыми штуками
Так происходит при выборе любой кисти,при изменении всех параметров остаётся все так же, такое ощущение что оно ходит по одной оси или что-то такое, что делать ?

Comment: Opacity у кисти уменьшить

Answer (score 0):

Уменьшить opacity у кисти.

Ваше opacity
[image: opacity]

Уменьшенное opacity

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]